How can one know the starting time of time clause that uses since as its conjunction and a durative verb as its predicate?
How to determine the starting time of a sentence with this structure: have done sth since sth was done? Is there any rule about this?
For exmaple,

It has been 3 years since I worked in this company.

In the first sentence, my grammar textbook explains it means "It has been three years since I last worked here in this company. I have not worked in this company during the past three years".


I have wanted to be a pilot since [=ever since] I was a boy.

In the second sentence, I guess the starting point is the early stage of boyhood.

But, in the third and forth sentences, I cannot be sure whether the starting point is the beginning of the action with the since clause or the ending of the action.

The house has been in bad repair since he lived in it.

Is the starting point of the house being in bad repair as of the moment that he moved into the house or from the moment he moved out of the house ?

He has never come to see me since I was ill.

Is the starting time the moment that I became sick or after I healed, that he has then never come to see me?


I wouldn't know whether you were saying that you left the company three years ago or have been working there for three years. "this company" suggests the latter, in which case "worked" is the wrong verb with since.  It has been three years now since I started working for this company.

If the former, that you left:  It has been three years now since I stopped working for that company.

My grammar book explain there is a rule: if the verb in the since clause is durative( for example: work, live, talk), then we should count time after the state of verb  is finished. For example, It has been 3 years since I worked in this company. This means, I It has been 3 years since  I stopped working there.

But it against my intuiation, so I gave the second example which comes a dictionary. I think it does not follow the rule given by my grammar textbooks.

As for the last two sentences which comes from another grammar textbook, in my life experience, their start time points cannot be deduced.

There doesn't have to be a definite 'starting point'. The speaker began to have the ambition of being a pilot at some stage in his childhood (presumably once he was old enough to know what a pilot does!). In the case of "He has never come to see me since I was ill", common sense indicates that the speaker would have expected to be visited while they were ill.

In your first diagram, the green word should be worked, not working.

I have wanted to be a pilot since [=ever since] I was a boy. wanted covers the period you were a boy UNTIL now. [Please be more careful with spelling.]

Define a durative verb in your question, please.

The verbs in above sentence: work, be, live are all durative verbs which can exist for a period of time versus leave, come. There are more example in the grammar textbook:  It has been a while since we talked.  (here talked is a durative verb);  It's been two years since I was in this university. (been is a durative verb)

The book explains that:  It has been a while since we talked. = It has been a while after we talked.   It's been two years since I was in this university. = It's been two years after I graduated from this university.

Your grammar book is wrong if it says that " It has been 3 years since I worked in this company" means "It has been 3 years since I stopped working there". The first sentence isn't quite idiomatic. First, "this company" suggests you are still with the company; we would say "that company" when speaking about a company we have left, unless we have returned to speak with a coworker we were friendly with, and having lunch in the company cafeteria, for example. It has been three years since I worked there would mean that I left there three years ago.

Maybe it's just me, but I would understand It has been 3 years since I worked in this company to mean 'since I last worked here'.

@KateBunting But you'd have to explain "here".  Why not "there"?  If the speaker is no longer with the company, "here" would suggest the speaker has returned for a visit or something.

You cannot "deduce" the time if the utterance is not idiomatic.  Native speakers know they must say something other than "worked".

@TimR - Well, yes, if you like the speaker is visiting their old workplace. But the discussion was about the meaning of 'X years since I worked...'.

Maybe part of the issue with your struggle is that some of your examples are a bit off.

The house has been in bad repaired repair since he lived in it.

The tense of the word "repair" isn't right, so I can't tell if you mean "since he lived in it", which means since he stopped living there, or "since he began living in it". If you can clear up that ambiguity, you'll know the starting point of this period.
The point of sentences like these is sometimes not to inform an amount of time, but rather to state that something has 'always' been the case. In that last example, if you already know how long "he" has been living in the house then you know, but if you don't, you don't.

He has never come to see me since I was ill.
He has not come to see me since I became ill.

This one is wrong partially because "never" ideally shouldn't be used within a finite setting. To say something has "never happened" usually means never ever, although you can qualify it, for example "he has never visited me in this house" could mean he has visited them elsewhere.
To sum up and answer your main question - nobody can calculate an amount of time unless there is a fixed starting point. That's why some of your examples were off, because they didn't give or weren't clear about a fixed event like "since I began [x]". Other times, the speaker/writer may only intend you to have a rough or estimated time frame if they say something like "since I was a boy". Even if they said "since I was 8 years old" relies on you knowing their precise age now for an exact time. But the length of time is not always the point of statement - it could just be to demonstrate that something has always been there, or that it was there since a young age etc. To get these types of statements right in English (or any language, I would expect) one has to have a clear understanding of the different ways of referring to time and events.

My grammar book explain there is a rule: if the verb in the since clause is durative( for example: work, live, talk), then we should count time after the state of verb is finished. For example, It has been 3 years since I worked in this company. This means, I It has been 3 years since I stopped working there.  Is this rule true?

The sentences you strike through are grammatical...

@lambie I never said they were ungrammatical, I said they were "a bit off". They might be understandable but would be clearer if revised to clarify the timing, and the timing is what the question is all about, so let's get them right.

Well, in crossing them out, it looks like you are discounting them altogether.

what I really want to know is whether there is a such "rule" : It has been a while since we talked. = It has been a while after we talked.
It's been two years since I was in this university. = It's been two years after I graduated from this university.
It has been 3 years since I worked in this company. = It's been two years after I leave this company.

I think this "rule" may be suitable for some sentence for estimate the length of time, but not for other type of sentence.
